# 18.04: How to allow normal (no sudo users) to be able to connect to a wireless network

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04

In Ubuntu 18.04 non-sudo users can't connect to the Wifi.  The would have to have access to log in with a sudoer user account, then log out, then log in as a normal user to have access to connecting to a wifi network.

That's a lot of work for a normal user, in order to connect to the wifi.  Also, there are some environments where the sudoer users' passwords are can be a security concern for distribution.

Can someone advise what has to be done (which group access) will allow non-sudo users to be able to connect to the wifi?

I'm not sure if it has always had this limitation before 18.04, but I'm just noticing it when trying to provide assistance to one of my clients who is out of town at a conference.  The administration account isn't a secret from him, but his computer literacy level is problematic for being able to do all the needed account switching to get connected.